# Is it not a good practice to have logic in dao side?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entity `A` and `A` has set of entity `B`. I do lazy loading. When I load all of the `A` results list I need to have a transient value for each `A` that has the size of `B` for that `A`.

In the service layer I can not do this as I performed a lazy loading. I have to set the transient value in the `dao` side. But I have heard not to have logic in `dao` side.

What should I do? Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Why couldn't you do that in the service layer? The transaction should be open and closed in the service layer, and not in the DAO layer, so lazy-loading doesn't cause any problem. That said, what's the point of this transient variable, since it would hold the same value as `A.getBs().size()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [Hibernate count collection size without initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913160/hibernate-count-collection-size-without-initializing) you can have the lazily loaded collection loaded with its size

Which seems like it will meet your requirements...

Comment: I tried to define it as a lazy collection as @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
 private List<Product> products; But got an exception org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.cellcity.cbtl.dao.domain.ProductCategory.products, could not initialize proxy - no Session....Any Ideas?

Comment: A quick google suggests it's a transaction issue. You're getting to the point where you need to add code to your question so people can see what's happening... it may just be that LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA isn't appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks Paul.It worked when I set @ManyToOne @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY) in the many to one side.I think it might because I have set mappedBy property to the One sides variable.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate need not be an "all or none" solution.  You are free to choose straight JDBC when it suits your purposes.

I'd recommend writing that simple `SELECT COUNT() FROM B` query in the DAO of your choice and getting on with things.

Or perhaps you should ask yourself why a DAO for A needs the size of B all the time.  I think DAOs ought to be stateless.  Why aren't yours?  Maybe the design should be reconsidered.  I can't tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be such a method in my `ADao`:

```
 public void loadBs( Collection<A> as ) {
 }
```

The code in the method should collect all foreign keys into a single select statement and then load all `B`s at once and distribute them over the `A`s they belong to.

That way, business/service code can decide for which group of `A` all dependent `B`s should be loaded and all of them can be loaded in one go.

Edit: The statement "no logic in the DAO" refers to "no **business** logic in the DAO". A DAO should give your business/service layer a fast and comfortable access to the underlying data structures. But if you start moving business logic down there, you will eventually strangle yourself in a web of dependencies.

A good example is some objects have a "valid time range". A time range is defined as `start < end` but is it a good idea to move this check into a DAO?

What happens if you try to load an object to edit, say, it's name but the time range is invalid? Would it be really useful if the DAO layer refused to load such an invalid object?

Or should the DAO to be able to load even completely invalid objects and all validation should happen in the business layer? Or in the UI layer when the user can actually do something about it instead of staring helplessly at an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that you could do that since adding that piece of extra information to your entities can be seen as part of data access and not business logic.

But that's only regarding the question about violation of design principles. Paul D'Ambra's suggestion of leveraging hibernate's potential for your needs seems like a more elegant solution.