# How can I get a count from a related table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 simple POJOs placed in a many to one relation

```
@Entity
public class Meeting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int meetingId;
    private String title;
    @ManyToOne
    private Location location;
    ...
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int locationId;
    private String name;
    ...
```

I'm wondering what do I need to do to get the count of meetings inside the **locationList** below

```
    Session session = HibernateHelper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Location> locationList = session.createCriteria(Location.class).list();
```

I've thinked of definig a @Transient meetingsCount inside the Location POJO but I don't know how to go on in order to tell Hibernate to retrieve it for me.

I do know how to get this information by making an explicit query but this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913160/hibernate-count-collection-size-without-initializing) post useful.

Comment: I think..If you have bidirectional mapping then you will have meeting list in location...if it is than you will get the count easy..

Comment: You want the count of meetings with respect to location?

Comment: I'll be posting an answer in about 12 hrs..

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is via formula.
It has some performance hit, but is quite helpful when need to return count for each fetched entity.
Add the following to Location entity:

```
@Formula("(SELECT count(m.id) FROM meeting m WHERE m.location_id = id)")
private Integer meetingsCount;
```