# If I call size() on a lazy collection, will Hibernate fetch it?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, collections

When we use one to many relational mapping with Hibernate (say one house, many windows) and call the method like `house.getWindows().size()`, will Hibernate be smart enough to invoke `select count`? Or, alternatively, it will fetch all rows from the `window` table that are mapped to the row in the `house` table?

Counting children by iteration may be highly inefficient, as lots of data about windows would be fetched without any need. Is `size()` equally bad? And would `size()` work at all if the result set limit is configured somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection normally will be initialized in case `size()` is called but this can be changed with additional annotations.

If you want a `SELECT COUNT` query to be executed then you need to specify some additional annotations or XML attributes.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913160/hibernate-count-collection-size-without-initializing) SO discussion for the exact details.