# Eagerly fetch associated collection size without initializing collection

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, one-to-many

I have an entity which is associated to another via a One-to-Many relationship.

When i load the entity i want to load only the size of the associated collection(how many entities is this one associated with) & i want to do it in an EAGER way so that this is fetched at the time the base entity is fetched(in a single Query).

[Hibernate count collection size without initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913160/hibernate-count-collection-size-without-initializing) shows how to do it in a Lazy way . I want to do it in eager way since i have some UI feature based on this and don't want to query multiple times.

Could use Formula but they are not HQL supporting.Any other way in hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has an annotation called Formula that should work for you:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785

Comment: as i mentioned in question - Formulas are not HQL supporting. I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HQL query for this purpose:

```
select e, (select count(c) from Entity e1 join e1.collection c where e1.id = :id)
from Entity e
where e.id = :id
```

Comment: I want to put this data into the entity class and auto fetch it while it gets loaded so this logic stays in a single place. how do i do that with above?